# CMD - How to remove a connection in Network and Sharing Center

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I like to know that isn't there anyway to do following using a batch file or a command script.

Control Panel > All Control Panel Items > Network and Sharing Center > Change adapter settings > Select any connection I desire > Delete it.

Isn't there any command to do so?

Thank You.

Comment: `netsh interface set interface /?`

Comment: @Stephan Thanks, I am still testing this command.

Comment: @Stephan It is a useful command, but there is no any `Delete` option in `netsh interface` in Windows 7. But SS64 shows there should be a `Delete` commmand with `netsh interface`. :-|, But as `netsh ras show wanports` showed my connection, I keep trying `netsh` commands. ;-)

Comment: there is a "disconnected" and a "disabled". Do you want to remove it from device manager? (btw: `netsh interface delete` is not meant to remove an interface. Only valid "device" is `helper`, which removes a helper DLL)

Comment: @Stephan Yes, to remove it from here. I think it isn't possible. right?

Comment: not sure, didn't try yet. Take a look at [devcon](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/devcon.php)

Comment: Get NIC names and index
`wmic nic get name, index`

Enable/disable NIC with index xx, (ie: 12)
`wmic path win32_networkadapter where index=12 call enable`
`wmic path win32_networkadapter where index=12 call disable`